# Help of libreoffice does not work after Ubuntu 20.04 dist-upgrade (object not accessible insufficient user rights)

Tags: permissions, libreoffice

When i do F1, the help window appear and a message alert also :

*Object not accessible. The Object cannot be accessed due to insufficient user rights.*

[libreoffice help do not open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLpyR.png)

I understand what it means, but how could i figure out WHICH object does have insufficient permissions ?

- Where could be the full logs ? how make them be written somewhere to be read ?
- How could i know WHICH object or folder to fix ?
- Full purge and reinstall of libreoffice package didn't help.
- Default language use didn't help.
- reintializing of user libreoffice profile didn't help.
- help didn't help help ;-)

An hint someone please ?

Comment: Seems this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1869561), feel free to add yourself as affected.

Comment: Thanks mook765 ! just added a comment to backtrack here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug 1869561](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1869561), it is not solved.

Temporarily you can use the help from web browser by opening `/usr/share/libreoffice/help/index.html` location.

Or use newer version of LibreOffice from the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: ok thank you all. the link [file:///usr/share/libreoffice/help/index.html] is working. (and redirect to my language automatically)

Answer (score 5):

A known bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1869561

According to that report a fix is in the pipeline.  Meanwhile, to see help, open a browser and go to file:///usr/share/libreoffice/help/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Only an idea, but... the terminal command `sudo dpkg -l | grep libreoffice-help` should show you the name of the package where libreoffice help is located. At my laptop, there are two packages called libreoffice-help-common and libreoffice-help-en-us.

And the command `locate libreoffice-help-common` will show you the locations of the files.

Comment: i did "sudo chmod -Rv a+r ..." on all the involved files told by the locate command. didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Had 3 installations of Libreoffice:

1. Snap
2. Old Ubuntu Software Center.
3. Deb download from libreoffice.org.

I removed all of them and killed soffice.bin in processes. Then in Software Center (Snaps) Installed fresh Libreoffice Version: 6.4.4.2

Rebooted. Now Help works with the indexed entries and no access error.